# Modifying a line of text when creating a tag

Tags: svn, batch-file, tortoisesvn

When I create a branch, I would like a hook script that will change the first line of the text file, to record the revision number. The reason I want to do this, is because this text file interfaces with other scripts that then extract the correct revision of other files from the repository.

I feel there must be a way of writing a pre-commit hook script that says if you are commiting to a certain path it changes a line of text, pre commiting.

```
Set "SVNHEAD=SVN HEAD"
set REPOS=%1%
Set "SVNREV=%REVISION%" (get the revision number somehow from SVN)

gsar -s%PARTSDIR:I:\=I::\% -r%SVNHEAD% -i -f %SVNREV%
```

The executable gsar replaces lines of text in ascii files, if theres an easy way of doing it .bat file though I would be really grateful to hear it. Does anyone have any idea if this is possible/how to do it?

Many thanks
Chris

Answer (score 1):

- You **can't get** future Revision number in hook, because it just not exist yet. You **can't predict** Revision number, because it can be "HEAD"+N (where N - **any** positive number): don't forget about simultaneous parallel commit nature
- Modify transaction-content in hook considered as extremely bad practice, which everybody must to avoid
- If you want to have Revision-Number in file, you can (have ?) to use SVN-keywords.

$Revision$ keyword will be translated to string, which contain (among other data) revision of last-commit of this file, i.e, in your case - revision of creating branch and will contain this data unless you modify file inside branch

- If $Revision$ trick isn't usable for you, you can rely on other data

  - `svn log -q BRANCH-URL` return in last data-string revision of creating branch
  - With additional commit after branching you can `svn propset somepropertry somevalue BRANCH-URL` and read it later with propget|proplist (somevalue=revision of branching, because it already exist)

In your situation *I'll prefer* to use special (unused for other tasks) file, which have to be created immediately before branching and commited only once in branch-revision only (not elegant, but simplest way)